# javascript private property syntax unrecognised

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Question clarification:

Specifically, Id like to know how the example below can be written without typescript. Understanding how to declare properties on classes etc. would be useful to me. I believe it should be possible to use blueprintjs (which is written in typescript), without using typescript in my implementations.

---

I'm following docs at:http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#components.toaster.js.react

There is sample code like this:

```
import { Button, Position, Toaster } from "@blueprintjs/core";


class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    private toaster: Toaster;
    private refHandlers = {
        toaster: (ref: Toaster) => this.toaster = ref,
    };

    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={this.addToast} text="Procure toast" />
                <Toaster position={Position.TOP_RIGHT} ref={this.refHandlers.toaster} />
            </div>
        )
    }

    private addToast = () => {
        this.toaster.show({ message: "Toasted!" });
    }
}
```

But I get `Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected ( (5:16)` which is the 'toaster' after 'private'. I am not precompiling typescript. I'm using es6 with webpack. How would I re-write this sample code to work with my environment?

Thanks.

Comment: *"Blueprint is written in TypeScript, a statically typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to plain JavaScript. All the code samples throughout this site and all interactive examples are also written in TypeScript."* http://blueprintjs.com/docs/

Comment: There are no property access modifiers, not class properties, and no type declarations in EcmaScript 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it. I got a bit of help from webpack based on this tutorial: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html. I set the target in the tsconfig.json configuration file to es6, and this is what webpack compiled to (more or less).

Any manual improvements to this solution welcome.

```
import {Button, Position, Toaster} from "@blueprintjs/core";

class ToastLauncher extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.refHandlers = {
            toaster: (ref) => this.toaster = ref,
        };

        this.addToast = () => {
            this.toaster.show({ message: "Toasted!" });
        };

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={this.addToast} text="Procure toast" />
                <Toaster position={Position.TOP_RIGHT} ref={this.refHandlers.toaster} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ToastLauncher
```

Answer (score 2):

blueprintjs is implemented using typescript, and that example is using typescript syntax.

See: http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#TypeScript

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'm now researching typescript here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html. Is it compatible to have some of my code written in ES6 transpiled by webpack, and then write some of my components in typescript?